# Declaring multiple variable in url using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass some variables to another page using javascript at present i am passing a single variable in url the url is looks like this

```
var PageToSendTo = '../xxxx/xxxx.php?appid=4&score='+score;
```

In at this script score is a javascript variable it is working fine now i want to pass another variable also along with this script

```
var java_var;
```

How i am trying to do is something like this

```
var PageToSendTo = '../xxxx/xxxxx.php?appid=4&score='+score'&javavar='+java_var;
```

But it is not working properly what is happening here and how to resolve this?.

Comment: You are missing the `+` operator after `score`. What exactly do you expect `score'&javavar'` to do? You can't just put two operands after each other like this. Btw, the browser tells you what the problem is. Seems like a good moment to learn how to debug JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var PageToSendTo = '../xxxx/xxxxx.php?appid=4&score='+score+'&javavar='+java_var;
```

Notice `+java_var` in the end of url.

and yes also according to @Felix `+` is missing in the url.

Comment: That's only part of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing a variable (`java` instead of`java_var`) and are missing a `+`.

This code:

```
var PageToSendTo = '../xxxx/xxxxx.php?appid=4&score=' + score '&javavar=' + java
```

. . . should be this:

```
var PageToSendTo = '../xxxx/xxxxx.php?appid=4&score=' + score + '&javavar=' + java_var
```